# iPad app terminating with nsrangeexception

Tags: ios, ipad

The app works fine on the simulator but on the iPad it crashes every time. From the console output I see that the crash is due to an uncaught NSRangeException when attempting to access index 0 of an NSMutableArray. I did not use any mutable arrays in my code and the last two lines of the call stack are:

```
25 comtest                                      0x000d5993 main + 82
26 comtest                                      0x000d593c start + 40
```

I'm thinking this is a problem outside of the code I have written.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing else in the stack trace that might have anything to do with your code? Try setting a breakpoint in appDidFinishLaunching:withOptions. If it doesn't hit that before crashing, then it's probably not your fault. If it does, move that breakpoint down until you find the crash location. What SDK are you using?

Comment: I'm using 4.3...can I use breakpoints when I run an app on the iPad itself?  Because as I said, it works fine on the simulator.  Thanks.